# Javascript Object Identities

Tags: javascript

Objects in JavaScript have unique identities. Every object you create via an expression such as a constructor or a literal is considered differently from every other object.

What is the reason behind this?

```
{}==={}//output:false
```

For what reason they are treated differently? What makes them different to each other?

Comment: That's how most object-oriented languages work. Two objects are unequal. Even when they have the same type and all their private and public variables have the same values, they are still two separate objects, so they are not equal.

Comment: Don't question language design on stack overflow. You never know what the language authors were thinking.

Comment: @JanDvorak: But many language authors did discuss their ideas in public, or wrote books where they reason about the language design. I think this question is legitimate, though the answer might be more general (cross language)

Comment: It is useful to consider the terms "equal" and "identical" and to understand how they differ. Two objects can be equal (they have the same contents) but they are NOT THE SAME ONE i.e. they are not IDENTICAL. The === operator checks identity, not equality. Therefore {}==={}, which creates 2 objects, is false.

Comment: @JohnDvorak I don't think he's questioning their reasoning for doing this, he's asking, in literal terms, why {} is not equal to {}. I did not realize that the object literal `{}` was essentially `new Object()`, which is probably the type of thing he's looking for

Comment: @JohnDvorak:  I think that the reasoning of language designers tends to have profound implications for how to use the language.  Or, perhaps, that the facts of how to use  language can be harmlessly "misidentified" as the intentions of the authors, in the same way that people say "our lungs were not 'designed' to do this, that or the other thing".  If you believe in evolution, or lungs were not "designed" to do anything, they just evolved.  But the syntactic shorthand is clear, concise, and useful.

Although, I will confess, too much syntactic sugar can cause cancer of the semicolon.  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are different instances of objects, and can be modified independently. Even if they (currently) look alike, they are not the same. Comparing them by their (property) values can be useful sometimes, but in stateful programming languages the object equality is usually their identity.

Comment: but what makes them different to each other since the instances share same properties and method .What is different?

Comment: If you pass one of them to a function that modifies it, the other will not change. I only know (default) equality by value from stateless programming lanuages.

Answer (score 12):

`{}` creates a **new** object.

When you try and compare two, separate *new* objects (references), they will never be equal.

Laying it out:

```
var a = {};  // New object, new reference in memory, stored in `a`
var b = {};  // New object, new reference in memory, stored in `b`

a === b;  // Compares (different) references in memory
```

If it helps, `{}` is a "shortcut" for `new Object()`, so more explicitly:

```
var a = new Object();
var b = new Object();

a === b;  // Still false
```

Maybe the explicitness of `new` helps you understand the comparison compares different objects.

On the other side, references *can* be equal, if they point to the same object. For example:

```
var a = {};
var b = a;

a === b;  // TRUE
```

Comment: @delnan "For what reason they are treated differently? What makes them different to each other?" - and my reason is that they are different references.

Answer (score 3):

This question is quite old, but I think the actual solution does not pop out clearly enough in the given answers, so far.

> For what reason they are treated differently? What makes them
> different to each other?

I understand your pain, many sources in the internet do not come straight to the fact:

**Object** (complex JS types => objects, arrays and functions) **variables store only references** (=address of the instances in memory) **as their value**. Object identity is recognized by reference identity.

You expected something like an ID or reference inside the object, which you could use to tell them apart (maybe that's actually done transparently, under the hood). But every time you instantiate an object, a new instance is created in memory and only the reference to it is stored in the variable.

So, when the description of the ===-operator says that it compares the values, it actually means it compares the references (not the properties and their values), which are only equal if they point to the exactly same object.

This article explains it in detail: https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0

BR
Michael

Answer (score 2):

The fact that they're different is important in this scenario:

```
a={}; 
b={}; 
a.some_prop = 3;
```

At this point you'll obviously know that `b.some_prop` will be undefined.

The `==` or `===` operators thus allow you to be sure that you're not changing some object's properties, that you don't want changed

Answer (score 0):

Both of the objects are created as a separate entities in the memory. To be precise, both of the objects are created as a separate entities on the heap (JavaScript engines use heap and stack [memory models](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) for managing running scripts). So, both of the objects may look the same (structure, properties etc.) but under the hood they have two separate addresses in the memory.

Here is some intuition for you. Imagine a new neighborhood where all houses are look the same. You've decided to build another two identical buildings and after finishing the construction both of the buildings are look the same and they even "sit" contiguously but still they are not the same building. They have two separate addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the simplest answer is "they are stored in different locations in memory".  Although it is not always clear in languages that hide pointers ( if you know C, C++ or assembly language, you know what pointers are, if not, it is useful study to learn a low level language ) by making everything a pointer, each "object" is actually a pointer to a location in memory where the object exists.  In some cases, two variables will point to the same location in memory.  In others, they will point to different locations in memory that happen to have similar or identical content.  It's like having two different URLs, each of which points to an identical page.  The web pages are equal to each other, but the URLs are not.