# How can I compare if two functions are constructed from the same code in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Note that this question focuses on comparing if two functions come from the same function definition. Not a general comparison of two objects (e.g. array, dates) in javascript.

In an example code like this:

```js
function father(num) {
  function generateChild() {
     console.log(num);
  }
  return generateChild;
}

const child1 = father(1);
const child2 = father(2);

// Tests:

console.log(child1 == child2); // false

console.log(child1 === child2); // false (as expected)

console.log(child1.prototype===child2.prototype); // false

console.log(child1.prototype.constructor===child2.constructor.prototype); // false

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(child1.prototype, 'constructor').value === Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(child2.prototype, 'constructor').value); // false 

console.log(child1.toString() == child2.toString()); // true.
```

How can I know that `child1` and `child2` are the same generateChild function?

Even though the `toString()` example works. I don't want to use toString here. Two functions could match their `toString()` value but be defined with the same code in two different places, thus, they are two different functions that happen to have the same code. e.g.:

```
function test(){console.log('test')}
function test(){console.log('test')}
```

`test1.toString() === test2.toString()` // this is true. but they are not really the same function as in the case of `generateChild`

Notice that this is specially complicated since the function is defined inside another function and runs in a closure. There are simple ways to compare functions such as `Array.prototype.map === Array.prototype.map`. This is true for example, but it is not the same case.

It is also interesting to note, that the browser devtools knows they have the same constructor defined in the same place. Constructors in the devtools seem to have a `[[FunctionLocation]]` that it is not available in runtime.

---

*Note about object comparison and other questions:*
Other questions such as [How can I determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-can-i-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects) and similar focus on comparing two objects e.g. compare `{a:1} == {a:1}` or `[1,2] == [1,2]` which can be compared using key/value comparison or iterating through values, but this is something that can't be done with functions.

Though very similar, tt differentiates from [Javascript comparing if 2 functions are exact same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49663462/javascript-comparing-if-2-functions-are-exact-same) because this function is defined inside another function.

Comment: your `father` function when called returns a function. So those `child1` and `child2` they both contain the same function and if you compare them doing `child1 === child2` it will return true

Comment: @DiegoD sadly `child1 == child2` returns false. It was one of the first checks I tried.  https://codepen.io/academo/pen/YzdRKqa?editors=0012

Comment: yes you are right... that's because the father function call is actually returning two different function objects each time. I had to check before saying. Well ... I can't suggest an appropriate solution that will go beyond the string comparison of the two functions as you already showed. The further thing I could say is to just define the `generateChild` function in an outer scope to make the previous strategy correct

Comment: This is a duplicate but DON"T use the accepted answer study the others with actual code.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I see the pinned question focus in objects in general and even though a function is an object my question focus exactly on functions. All the answers in the other questiona are about objects (as in {}). Arrays, Dates, etc.. If you can point me to an specific answer there I appreciate it.

Comment: I added a few more examples - only you can determine which best suits "equality" for your use case.  IS this an X/Y problem? i.e. what problem are you really trying to solve here? or just a generic one.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss thanks but none of those work for my case. I appreciate your efforts to provide an answer but none of those questions answer my problem, specially since all of them are marked as duplicated. 

I understand the rush to try to close a question and get some points but I think this is a legitimate question that deserves its own answers and research.

Comment: Please edit your question with MORE details on why it is not a duplicate since this has been asked so many times prior to clearly delineate from those.  There are, due to that a lot more questions of similar nature here.

Comment: No one gets points for closing questions as duplicates. There are better duplicates, however. For instance, [how do I compare 2 functions in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9817629/215552), [Javascript comparing if 2 functions are exact same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49663462/215552), etc...

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss None of the questions you linked as duplicate are about comparing functions, by source code location. They are all about comparing objects by their property values.

Comment: @academo As stated in the threads linked by Heretic Monkey, functions are object and their default equality is object identity, explaining why `child1 == child2` is false. So what do you actually mean by "same"? What is your use case, why would you want/need to know?

Comment: @Bergi I'd love to know how to better explain the question. For example in devTools. one can observer the whole descriptor of a constructor function and there's a property there called `[[FunctionLocation]]`. It points to the line and file that defined the function constructor. I want to find how to identify if two functions come from the same location. Another example `Array.prototype.add === Array.prototype.add` this is true, because it is an easy comparison, but the moment a parent function get's involved things get complicated

Comment: I don't think it is possible (other than comparing the toString value). the "child" and "father" functions are not related in any way, the "child" function is a brand new function each time you call the father function and it is not connected in any way to the father function.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I also checked those answers. They are very close to what I am asking. specially the second. The question here gets more complicated when you involve the function being defined another function and not in a global scope. Thanks for pointing them out!

Comment: @academo about [[FunctionLocation]] it seems like in the browser it is not possible but it might be possible in node https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146373/access-function-location-programmatically

Comment: @sney2002 sadly I need this in the browser :( But this is a good clue to keep looking. Thanks!

Comment: I would like to see your example changed to include a variable to indicate how you intend for it to behave under closure. e.g. `function father(x) { function generateChild() { return x; } return generateChild; }`.  And then I need to know how you'd like to comparing `father(1)` to `father(1)` or if we're comparing `father(1)` to `father(2)`.  Note that the stringified version of `generateChild` is the same even if the functions return different values of `x`.

Comment: @Wyck great suggestion! I modified the snippet and added a comment about it.

Comment: @academo Yes, you've clarified your question already that you care about the *[[FunctionLocation]]*, but as you found out, that information is only available to the debugger and not to runtime code. So the answer is: that is not possible. If you'd like us to suggest an alternative that could work for you, you'll need to tell us what problem you are trying to solve with this. What do you think you need this for? Notice that source code location is not an indicator of two functions doing the same thing, they could close over different values.

Comment: @Bergi I've been trying to find a way to do this for a while and I was also afraid that this is simply not possible. I decide to ask the internet to see if someone maybe had a different idea. I need this to intercept function calls inside a Proxy and return a distorted version of the function. Basically: if `function A` is called, I want to detect is called and return instead `function AModified`. I'm using a library called near-membrane and most of the time I can do this using Object descriptors. but in this case of a function inside a function I can't figure how to do it properly

Comment: @academo Could you give a more specific example of how you are using that library and how you are distorting functions? I still don't get why you'd need to distinguish functions constructed by the same code. But if you really need to, it seems that near-membrane does a transpilation anyway, so you could actually insert unique location identifiers in the source code.

Comment: You should probably also take a stance on how you feel about functions that came from `eval` generated code for example and if _eval'd the same string_ is to be taken as _the same code_.  This just maybe explains why your task is impossible in general as stated, but maybe if you tighten up your requirements and define what _same code_ is, this could be answerable for a certain application.

Comment: @Bergi I'm implementing a sandbox for Grafana, so plugins can run isolated from the rest of the app. near-membrane doesn't come with any transpilation and the code we'll run is third party we can't rebuild to include some sort of identification. In this specific case I need to intercept calls to a `useHistory` history object from react-dom. But this `history` is constructed like in my example, function inside a function and I can't find an easy way to identify this specific call. I get the function in the interception, but I need to inspect it to find it is the one I want which is slow in perf

Comment: @academo For that, you'd usually intercept the `useHistory` call first, and return a decorated object that would then allow you to intercept the method calls.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to know if the function came from the same source code.

This is impossible to accomplish as not all JavaScript platforms can guarantee a unique identifier for source code origin.  For example, the JavaScript engine itself can compile a function from a string at runtime using `eval` raising questions as to where the source code came from.  With `eval` specifically, it may get marked with the location of the `eval` call that generated it, not somehow the location of where the source code string got its value, which doesn't even make sense if it's not a string literal in code somewhere.

I think the closest thing you can get is to peel off the location of the code from the stack trace of an `Error` as explained in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/453028/1563833).  And then, since functions are objects, you can manually add a property that you will use to test the equivalence of two functions.  This of course only works for functions that you have specifically vetted and manually define their origin.  In situations where the stack trace doesn't provide a sufficiently unique identifier, you can manually tag any function with an appropriate unique identifier.

The code might look something like this:

```
function father(num) {
  function generateChild() {
     console.log(num);
  }
  generateChild.equivalenceId = new Error().stack.split('\n')[1];
  return generateChild;
}

function mother(num) {
  function generateChild() {
     console.log(num);
  }
  generateChild.equivalenceId = new Error().stack.split('\n')[1];
  return generateChild;
}

const child1 = father(1);
const child2 = father(2);
const child3 = mother(1);
const child4 = mother(2);

function areEquivalent(child1, child2) {
  return child1?.equivalenceId !== undefined && child1?.equivalenceId === child2?.equivalenceId;
}

console.log(areEquivalent(child1, child2)); // true
console.log(areEquivalent(child1, child3)); // false
console.log(areEquivalent(child3, child4)); // true
```

If performance is an issue then just tag it manually `generateChild.equivalenceId = 'someUniqueString'`

Comment: +1 for the `equivalenceId` approach,                                                             although I'd recommend using a symbol or even a `WeakMap`.

Answer (score 0):

Some option could be compare 2 stack traces if an error is thrown inside a function.
If a function accepts argument we could provide a throwing argument.
Maybe somebody knows a better way how to throw the error.

```js
function father() {
    function generateChild(x, y) {
        return x * y;
    }
    return generateChild;
}

const same = [father(), father()].map(fn => {
    try {
    
        const proxy = new Proxy({}, { get(){ throw new Error('test') } });
        fn(proxy);
    
    } catch (e) {
        return e.stack.split('\n')[2].trim();
    }
}).every((item, i, arr) => console.log(item) || !i || item === arr[i - 1]);

console.log('functions are the same:', same);
```

Comment: My bad! I fixed the mistake in the question so they have the same name.

Comment: yes! I tried this, and, it works, except, performance is terrible. I was trying a similar thing exploiting the Error stack to identify the caller of a function but after doing some benchmarks I noticed a *80%*! decreased performance. This solution is plausible indeed! so might be as well an answer to the question, but won't work for my specific case since I'd be doing this way too often and tanking the performance of the code I am running.

Comment: This only works if you know the function you're working with, in which case you can just look at the source code to tell whether it's an "equal" function.

Comment: @Bergi if a function has arguments you can provide more complex array of proxy arguments throwing on property access , valueOf, etc. The only problem if a function doesn't use any arguments

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev A function may have arguments but still not access anything on them. Examples: `var x; function setX(v) { x = v; }` or `function eq(a, b) { return a === b; }`

Comment: @Bergi changed to Proxy, looks better, at least as a concept

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a hack but it was fun to implement, the idea is to make the function to throw an exception and then extract the line number from the exception stack trace. the script accomplish this by passing parameters where the valueOf method throws an exception.

The line number corresponds to the place where the exception was thrown not where the function was defined. but given that they are from within the function it will tell you that in fact the two are from the same function.

this will only work if the function meet the following conditions:

- it has parameters
- they are used in a way that the valueOf method is called (math, ==, <, >...)

The script uses a regex to extract the information, it may fail if the stack trace is in another format. It includes two regex for chrome and firefox

```js
function getFunctionLocation (fn) {
    var args = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < fn.length; i++) {
        args.push({valueOf: function() { throw new Error() }});
    }

    try {
        fn(...args);
    } catch(e) {
        // the error within the function is at the 2 line of the stack trace
        var parts = getLocationFromTrace(e.stack)
        if (parts) {
            return {
                name: parts[1],
                file: parts[2],
                line: parts[3],
                column: parts[4]
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

function getLocationFromTrace(trace) {
    trace = trace.split("\n");
    var regexp = [
        /at ([^\s]+) [(](.*?):(\d+):(\d+)[)]/, // chrome
        /(.*?)@(.*?):(\d+):(\d+)/, // firefox
    ];
    var stackStart = 0;
    
    // find line in which the stack trace start
    // This is required because in chrome the first line is the exception name
    // but firefox the first line is the first location of the trace
    for (var i = 0; i < trace.length; i++) {
        var match = regexp.find(function(r) {
            return r.exec(trace[i]);
        });

        if (match) {
            stackStart = i;
            break;
        }
    }
  
    // find the correct regex to extract the information
    var correctRegExp = regexp.find(function(r) {
        return r.exec(trace[stackStart + 1])
    });

    return correctRegExp.exec(trace[stackStart + 1]);
}

function father() {
    return function child(a) {
      return a * 2;
    }
}

function externalScript(a) {
    if (a < 10) {
        return 10
    }
}

console.log(getFunctionLocation(inlineScript))
console.log(getFunctionLocation(externalScript));

var child1 = father();
var child2 = father();

var location1 = getFunctionLocation(child1);
var location2 = getFunctionLocation(child2);

// Both functions come from the same location
console.log(location1.file === location2.file && location1.line === location2.line)
```

```html
<script>
    function inlineScript(x) {
        return x + 2;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This is the same approach as already posted by @AlexanderNenashev, and has the same problem: it does not work for all functions, since many functions will not throw regardless what you pass to them.

Comment: @Bergi yes, I said in the answer that it only works in some situations, and I did see that there was already a similar answer, but I had already written the answer and code so I though I may as well posted it. also it improves it in passing all the required arguments which I think increases the possiblitity of it throwing an exception