# JavaScript OOP concept: what's the output?

Tags: javascript

How is the output true and why is there a need to explicitly returning the object as the new keyword creates an object and returns it automatically?

```
var obj = {};    
function A() { return obj; }
function B() { return obj; }
console.log( new A() == new B() );
```

Comment: You might want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817629/how-do-i-compare-2-functions-in-javascript

Comment: @NathanChampion no that did not help me at all

Comment: 1. The two are equal because they return the *same object*. Object are equal only to themselves. 2. If you don't explicitly return the object, then `new` *will* return difference instances, so they would be inequal. 3. It's not really clear why you really need the whole `new` and two functions for this. It boils down to `obj === obj`, the other things are just distractions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I compare 2 functions in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817629/how-do-i-compare-2-functions-in-javascript)

Comment: I disagree that "how do I compare 2 functions in javascript" is a dupe target. The question here isn't trying to compare *functions* but it's asking for specific outcome comparing the *result* of two functions when called with `new` operator. That's different to comparing two functions themselves.

Answer (score 1):

This code here is pretty convoluted for what's happening. It's not that complex it seems it's just throwing things together to be purposefully misleading. I suspect this is an interview question. I wouldn't class it as really good.

Let's break it down for ease:

## Object equality

> How is the output true

I'll remove the unneeded code to focus on the real thing. The code can be simplified to

```js
var obj = {};    
console.log( obj == obj );
```

It should be obvious why that would be true - you're comparing the *same thing to itself*. The result `true` is expected regardless<sup>1</sup> of the value of `obj`.

One additional thing we can mention here is that [objects are only equal to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704971/why-are-two-identical-objects-not-equal-to-each-other). That's distinct from other primitive types<sup>2</sup> where to values that are the same are also equal<sup>3</sup>. So two different objects will still be different even if they contain similar information:

```js
console.log("foo" === "foo"); //true
console.log(42 === 42);       //true

console.log({foo: "bar"} === {foo: "bar"}); //false
console.log({} === {});                     //false
```

<sup>1</sup> [There is one exception - the value `NaN`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values)

<sup>2</sup> Except [Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) which are primitives but by design each represents a unique value. It's *usually* not worth discussing them unless specifically focusing on Symbols, hence they are just a footnote here.

<sup>3</sup> I can't seem to formulate an explanation so it doesn't sound like a tautology.

---

## Return values for function

> why is there a need to explicitly returning the object as the new keyword creates an object and returns it automatically

This is the crux of the problem here. [How the `new` keyword operates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript).

Yes, `new` will create a new object instance when called with a function. However, if the function returns a non-null *object*, then that will be used as the return value and will override the instance creation:

```js
function Foo() {}            // <-- no `return` statement

function Bar() {
  return null;               // <-- returns `null`
}

function Baz() {
  return 42;                 // <-- returns a non-`null` but primitive value
}

function Quux() {
  return { hello: "world" }; // <-- returns an object
}

const foo  = new Foo();

console.log("typeof foo:", typeof foo);
console.log("foo instanceof Foo:", foo instanceof Foo);
console.log("foo:", foo);

const bar  = new Bar();

console.log("typeof bar:", typeof bar);
console.log("bar instanceof Bar:", bar instanceof Bar);
console.log("bar:", bar);

const baz  = new Baz();

console.log("typeof baz:", typeof baz);
console.log("bar instanceof Baz:", baz instanceof Baz);
console.log("baz:", baz);

const quux = new Quux();

console.log("typeof quux:", typeof quux);
console.log("quux instanceof Quux:", quux instanceof Quux);
console.log("quux:", quux);
```

Therefore if both `A` and `B` have `return obj` in their bodies *and* `obj` is an object, then calling `new A()` is the same as calling `A()`  without the `new` operator which is therefore the same as just `obj`. It's analogous for `B`.

```js
var obj = {};    
function A() { return obj; }

console.log( new A() == A() ); //true
console.log( A() == obj );     //true
console.log( new A() == obj ); //true
```

There is a *slight* curve ball here in that the task uses the abstract equality operator (`==`) which used is called "loose equality". I'm calling it a "curve ball" since it [works in some unintuitive ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons). However, it's only *slight* because none of this applies here - `==` will produce inconsistent results when the two operands are *different types* since it will trigger [abstract equality comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using). It's a common pitfall and hence it's standard to exclusively use strict equality comparison (`===`) which is consistent. Here is a quick example of inconsistency with `==`:

```js
const a = "";
const b = 0;
const c = " ";

//comparing a string and a number - string is converted to a number.
//empty string `a` converts to a zero
console.log(a == b); //true

//comparing a string and a number again.
//spaces are trimmed from `c` and an empty string is left. It's again a zero
console.log(b == c); //true

//comparing two strings. Same base type - no conversion needed.
//two strings with different content are not equal
console.log(a == c); //false

//the `==` operator is not transitive
```

However, the operands here are not only the same *types* but literally the same *value*, so `==` will work exactly like `===`.

---

## Additional information

With all this explanation in place, it's *possible* that the question is just a setup. If the value of `obj` is changed then *everything* changes. If `obj` is anything other than an object (so, any primitive type, or `null`), then calling the functions with `new` will actually produce a new instance and thus the results would be different:

```js
var obj = 42;
function A() { return obj; }
function B() { return obj; }
console.log( new A() == new B() );
```

I've discussed it above but just in short

- the function returns a non-object value
- calling it with `new` produces a new instance
- two different instances are never going to be equal

Removing the `new` operator from *one* of the function calls will also produce `false`, as `A()` will now return the `42` while `new B()` produces an object. The two would not be equal.

If the `new` is removed from *both* the function calls, then the result is going to be the same for *almost* any value of `obj`. Anything except `NaN`.